# PrimeFaces Poll listener not called

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a jsf page with a p:poll tag with a listener and an update. The update is called but the listener is not.

I slowly removed sections from the jsf page until I narrowed down the issue to a `<f:validateLongRange>` tag. If I removed the validate the listener is called but with it in it is not.

The simplified jsf page is below. Why the validate would be causing issues with the poll?

I am using primefaces 3.5 and JSF 2.1 running on Tomcat 7.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/BasicTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="menuId">
    #{trackTabBean.setCurrentTab(trackTabBean.devicesTab)}
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
    <f:metadata>
                <f:viewParam name="cgId" value="#{deviceBean.inputControlGroupId}"
                    validatorMessage="Control Group Id must be between 1 and 254">
                    <f:validateLongRange maximum="254" minimum="0" />
                </f:viewParam>
                <f:viewParam name="devId" value="#{deviceBean.inputDeviceId}" />
                <f:event listener="#{deviceBean.loadDevice}" type="preRenderView"></f:event>
    </f:metadata>
        <h:form id="deviceForm">            
            test (Load more code here but removed for testing)      
            <p:poll interval="5" listener="#{deviceBean.updateDetails}" update="deviceForm"/>   
        </h:form>
        <h:form>

        </h:form>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not set/updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value)

Answer (score 2):

Your listener is not being called, as you probably have some validation errors. In the JSF Life-cycle Phase 3 is the "Process Validations" Phase, if this phase fails JSF will immediately jump to phase 6, which is "Render Response" Phase. So phase 5 "Invoke application" where the listener gets called, will be skipped.

Make sure that neither deviceBean nor inputControlGroupId is null and applies the given constraint.

```
#{deviceBean.inputControlGroupId}
```

Comment: Thanks Sonic, that seems to be on the right track. However neither _deviceBean_ nor _inputControlGroupId_ are null but the param doesn't always exist. The _cgId viewparam_ is an optional input param so when it is not defined I am getting the issue but when it is defined I don't. Also why don't I get some validation exception? I can remove the validation tag as it is not too important in my case but would be nice to fully understand what is going on.

Comment: As cgId is an optional param you should render the validation tag only if this param has been set. You can do this by adding a corresponding <c:if/> test. As the variable has not been set, you will get a RuntimeException Nullpointer Exception, not a checked Validation Exception, when JSF tries to access this parameter in it`s validation phase. This is why your program crashes.

Comment: If you you want to skip validation then use `immediate="true"`.  For example : `<p:poll interval="5" listener="#{deviceBean.updateDetails}" immediate="true" update="deviceForm"/>`